# browserstack requesting localhost:45691

Tags: browserstack

Anyone any idea why browserstack might be constantly requesting localhost:45691. When I open browserstack in Chrome I get this request continuously.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:45691. Origin http://www.browserstack.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In FF its showing a JS file causing the issue
localhost:45691/
http://www.browserstack.com/assets/bsjs.js?1376347645

Anyone having this issue? I even sent a report to browser stack 3 days ago and nothing either. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 6):

BrowserStack provides a feature of Local Testing via Command Line Tunnel. To check if tunnel is connected or not, their JavaScript(JS) tries to talk to a http server which runs on port 45691 inside BrowserStackTunnel.jar.

When you don't have this Command Line Tunnel set, then the JS gets these errors, which turns to 200 OK response as soon as tunnel gets connected.